# How to fetch data from database in batch in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose 5.12.3. I  wanted to fetch 100 and then do some function on that data and then again fetching next 100 data. I am trying to using  `.batchSize()`.

But got all data.

```
   const Participant= await ParticipantModel.find({},{emailId:1}).batchSize(100);
   console.log(Participant.length)
```

But it fetch docs more than 100.

How to use `.batchSize()` or any other way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Idk about the batch size but you can limit the number of items you calling by using `.limit`

```
ParticipantModel.find({}).limit(10);
```

Comment: I can't use limit as using limit I can't get data part by part. Using limit it will be like pagination and I don't have page information